# How can i Pull Profile image from sharepoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'am new in API's & trying to pull user profile from sharepoint i use following code but don't know about servername? domainname? and username?

```
const string serverUrl = "http://sharepoint.com/";
            const string targetUser = "ttgdev-my.sharepoint.com\\testuser1@ttgdev.guru";

            // Connect to the client context.
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(serverUrl);

            // Get the PeopleManager object and then get the target user's properties.
            PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
            PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(targetUser);

            // Load the request and run it on the server.
            // This example requests only the AccountName and UserProfileProperties
            // properties of the personProperties object.
            clientContext.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var property in personProperties.UserProfileProperties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}",
                    property.Key.ToString(), property.Value.ToString()));
            }
            Console.ReadKey(false);
```

Please guide me it will give me the error in 
**{"The property or field 'UserProfileProperties' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."}**
in the following line

```
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Is it SharePoint online or on premise?

Comment: no i want to access userprofile  picture only by using this

Comment: What no? I'm just asking about which SharePoint **version** are you using..

Comment: Vadim i'm making an app using MVC 5 i jst need to pull profile picture of user based on what is stored in Azure Active Directory and SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is related with the format of `targetUser` variable. [PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.peoplemanager.getpropertiesfor.aspx) expects `accountName` parameter to be specified in the proper format, in case of SharePoint Online it should be specified in claims format, for example:

```
i:0#.f|membership|jdow@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
```

> For more details about Claims format follow [this article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13921.sharepoint-2013-claims-encoding-also-valuable-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx).

So, in your case `targetUser` value should be replaced from `ttgdev-my.sharepoint.com\\testuser1@ttgdev.guru` to `i:0#.f|membership|testuser1@ttgdev.guru`

---

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve user profile picture via CSOM API:

```
using (var ctx = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(webUri.ToString(), accessToken))
{

    // Get the PeopleManager object and then get the target user's properties.
    var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(ctx);
    PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(targetUser);

   //Retrieve picture property
   var result = peopleManager.GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName, "PictureURL");
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   Console.WriteLine("Picture Url: {0}",result.Value);
}
```